# Is it possible to create a dashed or dotted line in photoshop below cs5?

Tags: photoshop

My Question is that, Is it possible to create a dashed or dotted line in photoshop below cs5 without using Brush or brush presets.

Thanks

Comment: Try asking here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question Try asking on [graphicdesign.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really do not want to use brushes (easy), then you can try a repeating pattern of one or two pixel wide option (hard). An intermediate approach is to:

1. create a text box with dotted lines
2. delete, mask, or wipe 3 of the 4 sides, keeping the one line you want.

Dotted lines is an option for text box boundaries. If you do them in layers, you can quickly repeat and duplicate them to speedup.